# Preserve original date of an edited post in the android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

When viewing a post that has been edited the date of creation is replaced by the date of the last edit.

I suggest to display the creation date as well - the line seems to provide sufficient space.

Use cases :

1. On AskUbuntu we determine if a question about an old release is off topic by looking at the date when it was asked. (only new questions about old releases are OT)
2. As it is currently not possible to see the revision history of a post this would provide a way to get a time context for the post.